# Array value arrangement

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, key-value-store

I have an array

```
Array ( 
   [0] => 1492,1,1,1 
   [1] => 1493,1,1,1 
   [2] => 1494,1,1,1 
   [3] => 1547,7,7,2 
   [4] => 1527,7,7,1 
   [5] => 1545,7,7,1 
   [6] => 1546,7,7,1
   [7] => 1537,7,7,1 
   [8] => 1539,7,7,1 
   [9] => 1529,7,7,2 
   [10] => 1538,7,7,1 
   [11] => 1555,9,9,1 
   [12] => 1530,7,9,1,or 
   [13] => 1528,7,9,1,or 
   [14] => 1553,9,11,2 
   [15] => 1554,9,11,2 
)
```

the `[3]` and `[9]` keys values have `2` in its last element(splitting by comma).

i want the `[9]` to be next to `[3]`

how to do this?

Comment: State your question clearly. Also add any existing code effort.

Comment: What you have try so far?

Comment: state your requirement clearly.

Comment: I guess you want to sort the array based on the last comma separated value? right?

Comment: yes, thats right..

Answer (score 0):

I found a function in another question that will help you out.

```
function moveElement(&$array, $a, $b) {
    $out = array_splice($array, $a, 1);
    array_splice($array, $b, 0, $out);
}

moveElement($array, 0, 2);
```

*Note* This is not my own answer.